# Show popup when MouseEnter event fires

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent, mouselistener, mouseenter

I  think messed everything up.  I have tried creating popup windows  when `MouseEntered` event fires. How can I fix this?

```
Popup p=factory.getPopup(c,null,x,y);
```

I am not sure about parameters

Rest of this code:

```
 public class pop extends JFrame{

  class mypopUpShow  implements ActionListener{
    JComponent c;
  //  final Random random;
 public mypopUpShow(JComponent c){
    this.c=c;
  }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Random random=new Random();
       int x = random.nextInt(200);
       int y = random.nextInt(200);
      PopupFactory factory=PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
      Popup p=factory.getPopup(c,null,x,y);
      p.show();
    }
   }
   public pop() {
    JPanel Panel=new JPanel();

  final Timer   t=new Timer(100, new mypopUpShow(Panel));
    MouseListener listener=new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me){
        t.start();
         }
 };
   setSize(300,300);
   Panel.addMouseListener(listener);

   add(Panel);
   }
   public static void main(String...arg){
   new pop().setVisible(true);
         }
   }
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  Please describe what you're seeing and what you expect to see.

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one. 4) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough. 5) Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: Hi jim as i said I have tried creating popup windows when mouseEntered event works.But i am getting exception  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Popup.getPopup must be passed non-null contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the 'contents' parameter for getPopup(Component owner,
Component contents, int x,int y) to null.   This is why you are getting an IllegalArgumentException.   Try changing null to something like "new JButton("TEST")" and you will see a ton of buttons popup.  The contents is what you want to popup (a widget, a panel, a window, etc).